# I can't click on my object in any mode

Tags: edit-mode

*can't click on any object in any mode*
I have just started blender and I have not made anything. I have been trying to make some dice. My functions work, but I can't click on anything in my scene. This annoying target follows my mouse around.

I am using Blender on rollapp
version 2.79

Comment: "annoying target" I can guess that you click with Left mouse button. By default Blender uses Right mouse button for selection. That "annoying target" is quite useful 3D cursor which is positioned with left click.

Comment: If you are going to learn blender you better think of the target as your new best friend... Also left and right clicking on blender do different things.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you are clicking with the wrong button. Use the <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> (often abbreviated as <kbd>RMB</kbd>).

The annoying target is called the [3D cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html) if you are talking about this.

[image: this]

This fellow will act as a kind of landmark and can be moved by clicking <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> (often abbreviated as <kbd>LMB</kbd>).

If this feels uncomfortable, you may remap it at the [user preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/index.html). 
[This](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Blender-use-right-click-to-select-instead-of-left-click) may help.

Also, if you have an experience in other 3dcg softwares, such as MAYA, using remapping presets maybe useful. They are accessible at the [Splash Screen](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/splash.html).

However, I recommend you NOT to remap the mouse buttons. Blender has some wonderful mouse button shortcuts and if you innocently remap buttons, you will lose them. Besides, you will get use to them.

Finally, if you are intersting in why blender adopted this peculiar UI, I've heard that this system reduces stress on the index finger. Indeed, I find my index finger exhausted on some other 3DCG software.

Good Luck